# Use enum defined in a struct as case constant in C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums, switch-statement

I have an `enum` as a member of a `structure` defined in a header file. 
For example,

```
struct abc{
    enum xyz{
        FIRST =1;
        SEC =2;
    }qw;
};
```

In my `.cpp` file , I have included this header. I have a `switch case` in my file where these `enums` are to be used as `case constants`.

```
struct abc az;
switch(az.qw){
case FIRST:....
case SEC:...
default:..
}
```

But I get error as `FIRST is not declared in this scope`. How to overcome the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `abc::FIRST`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xyz` is defined in the scope of `abc`, so you need

```
case abc::FIRST:
```

etc.

Comment: OH God!!.. Thankz a lot.. Tried a lot using `abc::qw::FIRST` and `abc.qw.FIRST` and `abc.FIRST`. But didnt try this.. Thank You..